# Finding group memberships via script given username and domain

Tags: scripting, hta, active-directory-group

I'm building a little toolkit wrapped into an HTA for use in a helpdesk.  One of the tasks I'd like to have included is the ability to quickly pull info about a domain user.  Now, normally, I would just use something like `Net User USERNAME /domain` and get a quick little blurb.  Works great.

However, I can't seem to find a way to integrate that into the script for the toolkit.  I could probably use cscript and just dump the output, but then I would have a heck of a time getting it formatted into anything interactive (the whole point of the HTA).

I'd really like to use something like ADSI. I can pretty easily get members of a given group, or the primary group of a given user, but I can't seem to find a way to list all the memberships of a username on the domain.

Note, that pulling all the groups and users, then comparing them is not an option. This is for a domain with hundreds of thousands of users.

I promise I have googled for days on this thing. Dug around in the documentation etc, but nothing really seems to do what I need.

Comment: Can't you read the information with cscript/wscript and save it to a temporary text file? Then just read the file in HTA and delete it after reading.

Comment: I could, and that would be fine for infodump, but I'd really like to get it into a parsable format so I can allow the tech to click on and edit items via javascipt from within the HTA.

Comment: There's JSON available from IE8 on... You're not doing this for older IEs or Quirks?

Comment: Nope, IE8+, but I had tried JSON and was thrown an error that it wasn't a valid object/resource etc.  Basically my js just went 'HUH?' when it did JSON.stringify.

Comment: Actually I've never tried JSON within wscript, but it isn't too hard to create a snippet which translates an object to a string. Any case, `JSON.parse()` is available in HTA for quick convert to an object again.

Comment: Hmm. Let me try that real quick. Might be useful, but I don't think it will get the data I'm looking for (all user's memberships).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with AD, but [ADRMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb403225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be interesting, especially [UserRightsItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object...

Comment: @Teemu - JSON still throwing not defined. ADRMS not going to get what I need.

Comment: Not defined in HTA? Please use `<!DOCTYPE html>` + `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">`. This `meta` should be placed just after `title`, at least before any `meta`, `script` or `link` tag. It's sad ADRMS didn't help, I wish you a good luck with this : ).

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to your comment about running `CSCRIPT` and dumping the output.

You can consider using the `WScript.Shell` object instead, specifically, the `Exec` method to run a command from within your HTA and make use of `stdout.readAll` to suck the output.

The following example shows how you would do this to capture the output of `IPCONFIG` into your HTA:

```
<html>
<head>
<hta:application icon="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"/>
<title>WScript.Shell Example</title>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub RunCommand
  Dim wshShell
  Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim wshExec
  Set wshExec = wshShell.Exec("IPCONFIG")
  textAreaResult.value = wshExec.stdout.readall
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body onload="RunCommand">
<textarea id="textAreaResult" style="width:100%;height:300"/>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```